# Google Map API in Foundation reveal modal not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zurb-foundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Map API inside a Reveal Modal not showing fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060779/google-map-api-inside-a-reveal-modal-not-showing-fully)

I have a Google Map API located within a Reveal Modal.  For those that do not know what that is, it is basically a hidden container that pops up when a button is clicked.  I have within this reveal modal the Google Map API, which is displaying, but not displaying all of the map, it is only showing maybe a third of it.

How do I get the whole map to display?

A link to my page:
http://simplicitdesignanddevelopment.com/Fannie%20E%20Zurb/foundation/contact_us.html#

CLICK ON THE GOOGLE MAP BUTTON TO SEE THE ISSUE AT HAND

The Reveal Modal script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myModal1').click(function() {
$('#myModal').reveal();
});
});
</script>
```

The Div which contains the Google Map API

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>
```

The button which when clicked, reveals the Google Map

```
<div class="five columns">
  <ul class="button-group even three-up" id="contact-button-group">
    <li><a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="myModal">Google Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you noticed, that if you keep the modal open and switch to another tab in the browser and switch back, that the full map is loaded?

Comment: Wow, thanks for bringing that to my attention. That is weird..I am wondering if it is because I have the map displayed in a hidden container.

Comment: inspecting element makes the whole map load also..hmmm

Comment: theres a kind of reload triggered that causes google to check the size of the container again, try to find a kind of refresh method like `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`

Comment: you already asked this very same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060779/google-map-api-inside-a-reveal-modal-not-showing-fully

Comment: Yes, he did. See my answer posted there.

Answer (score 5):

After the modal is shown use `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` where "map" is the instance of your map.

Comment: I have tried to get this working, and know that it is the answer, but I am very new at the whole js thing, and admit to the js I currently have is just copy and paste.  Where and how to do I put the event trigger to resize?  Do I put it in the google map api code that I already have?  Thank you for your time and help in this.  I am taking js next semester, and have very little understanding of syntax and how to put it all together.

Comment: I have been messing around with it and still haven't gotten it to work properly. Grrrrr

Comment: I see you got this working on your site, can you offer any help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321577/google-maps-api-v3-foundation-4-reveal-modal-not-displaying-properly ?